# Too many arguments in my IF statement

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I keep receiving an error message that my IF statement has too many arguments. I have used this formula in other excel workbooks and it has worked. Can anyone see what the problem is? Thank you for your help!

```
=IF(OR(AD2="22",AD2="23",AD2="39",AD2="540",AD2="541",AD2="836"),"1",IF(OR(AD2="335",AD2="312",AD2="364",AD2="367",AD2="311",AD2="336",AD2="365",AD2="319",AD2="368",AD2="488",AD2="498",AD2="461",AD2="501",AD2="505",AD2="531",AD2="462",AD2="489",AD2="491",AD2="491",AD2="493",AD2="507",AD2="457",AD2="460",AD2="499",AD2="503",AD2="509",AD2="513",AD2="539",AD2="612",AD2="613",AD2="568",AD2="821",AD2="827",AD2="829",AD2="835",AD2="845",AD2="846",AD2="615",AD2="620",AD2="614",AD2="691",AD2="719",AD2="873",AD2="877",AD2="32",AD2="427",AD2="373",AD2="465",AD2="502",AD2="511",AD2="466",AD2="475",AD2="481",AD2="500",AD2="504",AD2="462",AD2="489",AD2="491",AD2="493",AD2="507",AD2="503",AD2="513",AD2="539",AD2="607",AD2="610",AD2="608",AD2="609",AD2="611",AD2="579",AD2="769",AD2="795",AD2="827",AD2="831",AD2="834",AD2="837",AD2="838",AD2="839",AD2="840",AD2="841",AD2="842",AD2="843",AD2="851",AD2="852",AD2="853",AD2="854",AD2="856",AD2="857",AD2="860",AD2="861",AD2="868",AD2="869",AD2="870",AD2="871"),"2",IF(OR(AD2="521",AD2="524",AD2="535",AD2="536",AD2="557",AD2="558",AD2="805"),"3","4")))
```

Comment: Ewww.  Are you pasting to a new version of Excel or why is this now not working?  What changed?

Comment: What version of Excel? You could only nest up to seven IF statements like that in older versions.

Comment: It's fewer than 7 nested ifs, so that's not the issue. Works fine for me in XL2013

Comment: Any chance that cell `AD2` is misformatted in your new file?

Comment: Any value of AD2 should work and return 4 if not one of the strings. You probably have an errant comma in your formula. Did you post the formula that does not work, or a copy of the formula that works in another file? Try to copy and paste the formula you posted here.

Comment: what version of excel are you in?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I am using Excel 2007, and the formula I copied is the one that is not working. It has worked in other excel workbooks, all Excel 2007. I copied and pasted the formula into the new file and now it does not work. I have tried formatting cell AD2 as both a number or "general" and neither formatting will make the formula work.

Comment: Only problem I found is that `22` (_numeric_) returns _4_, while `'22` (_text_) returns _1_.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the error probably has to do with the limits of version you are using.
Since the formula contains fixed equivalences, I suggest to create a Define Name range then Vlookup cell AD2 to the table in order to obtain the related value:

[image]

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(AD2,_Table,2,0),"4")
```

Answer (score 0):

This formula should work fine in Excel 2007 and later (I just tested it in 2010 with no issues).  The maximum number of arguments allowed in a function in these versions is 255.  For earlier versions of Excel though, the max is 30. Since you did not specify which version of Excel you are using, I cannot be 100% sure if this is the problem though but I suspect this is what is going on.  I recommend you upgrade to a more current version of the software, but if that's not an option you could always break out the function among multiple cells (In particular, it's the 2nd nested if statement, with ~90 parameters that is causing this...).